# Unknown proof Lie Algebra

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a calculation where I do not know what it actually shows. I think it tells me that for right invariant vector fields, the commutator is again right invariant.

Maybe somebody here could help me with the notation.

Let $G = GL(N)$ $X_g = X_e g$ and $Y_g= Y_e g$
such that
$(X_g)_{li}= \sum_{k=1}^{N} (X_e)_{ik} g_{kj}$
and $(Y_g)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} (Y_e)_{ik}g_{k,j}$
 Then the calculation shows that ( I  only show the first and the last step)

$$([X,Y]_g)_{i,j}) = \sum_{k,l=1}^{N} \left((Y_g)_{k,l} \frac{\partial (X_g)_{i,j}}{\partial g_{k,l}}- (X_g)_{k,l}  \frac{\partial (Y_g)_{i,j}}{\partial g_{k,l}} \right) = ([X_e,Y_e]g)_{i,j}$$

The thing is that I would understand this calculation, if I knew what $g$ actually was. From context, I would guess that $g$ is something like a right-translation operator, but I don't know.
In especially, in this calculation that I abbreviated, it was used that $\delta_{m,k} \delta_{l,j} = \frac{\partial g_{m,j}}{\partial g_{k,l}}$ and I have no idea, where this comes from.

So first question: What is $g$?
Second question: Why are there derivatives in the commutator?(cause $X,Y$ are defined without any derivatives)

and third question: Why do we have this orthogonality condition for the derivatives of $g$?

Comment: A little context might help. What do you mean when you say you "have a calculation"? Did you find it in a book? or a research paper? If so, wouldn't it make more sense to look there for the definitions of the terms?

Comment: $g$ is a group element. Put another way, $g\in G=GL(N).$ Put yet another way, $g$ is an invertible $N$-by-$N$ matrix. Next, recall that vector fields on a manifold $M$ can be considered as derivations on $C^\infty$-functions on that manifold. For example, if $X$ is a vector field on $M,$ and $f$ is a smooth function on $M,$ then $X(f)$ is again a smooth function on $M.$ Now, if $Y$ is another vector field on $M,$ then we have by definition of the Lie bracket $[X,Y](f) = X(Y(f)) - Y(X(f)).$ If we calculate $X(Y(f))$ and $Y(X(f))$ in local charts, ...

Comment: ... then we have to apply $X$ to the coordinates of $Y$, and vice versa $Y$ to the coordinates of $X.$ That's where the terms $\frac{\partial (X_g)_{i,j}}{\partial g_{k,l}}$ and $\frac{\partial(Y_g)_{i,j}}{\partial g_{k,l}}$ come from. Regarding your last question, note that $GL(N)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^{N\times N}.$ This means that, for a given $g_0\in GL(N),$ there's a neighborhood $U$ of $g_0$ consisting entirely of invertible matrices. We can use this neighborhood as a chart for the manifold $GL(N).$ The coordinate functions for that chart $U$ are just the matrix entries. ...

Comment: Those matrix entries can vary freely and independently (around the given matrix $g_0$). In other words, we can vary one matrix entry while keeping all the others fixed. If we denote by $g$ the matrix of coordinate functions on $U,$ then the preceding sentence just states that $\frac{\partial g_{m,j}}{\partial g_{k,l}} = \delta_{m,k}\delta_{j,l}.$ If you're familiar with Lie groups, I suggest you read up on classical matrix groups.